# TVS diode identification

Tags: diodes, identification, tvs, dmx

I'm trying to ID diodes on a board - the markings on the diodes are "BK 9EJ3D". I understand this is a TVS diode and it's being used to clamp RS485 differential pair to ground with a termination circuit into a MAX 485 driver (485 to ttl). They measure around 730 ohm in both directions when I use a multimeter. Signal is something similar to DMX.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it is a TVS? If you know its package and role, just find a suitable replacement from one of the big vendors.

Answer (score 1):

The component might be an [SMF14A by Littelfuse](https://www.littelfuse.de/products/tvs-diodes/surface-mount/smf/smf14a.aspx), a unidirectional suppressor diode (i.e. a Zener designed for suppression purposes) with breakdown between 15.6 and 17.2 volts. Its marking code according to the datasheet is `BK`.